# Automated SOAP testing with maven and the SoapUI plugin

Tags: maven, soap, soapui

I am try to automate the SOAP UI with Maven3 .I am getting issue saying "Cannot be downloaded".Below is the error in console ..

[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/krishna/.m2/repository), eviwarePluginRepository (http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException"

To execute it I have adding the following

1) Added the plugins for eviware and jetty
2) added the plugin repository eviware repository.

Below is the pomy for the above 2 mentioned.

Please let me know if I am missing any thing.

org.mortbay.jetty

```
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.20</version>
    <configuration>
      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>8080</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
      <contextPath>/xyz-${project.version}</contextPath>
      <webApp>target/xyz-${project.version}.war</webApp>
      <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
      <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start-jetty</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <daemon>true</daemon>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-jetty</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin> 
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <projectFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/soapui/project.xml</projectFile>
      <printReport>true</printReport>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>soap-integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Its a proxy issue.Not able to connect to the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following in your settings.xml  (.m2/):

```
 <proxies>
   <proxy>
     <id>myproxy</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>172.18.65.22</host>
     <port>80</port>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```